# How to calculate the solubility of lead (II) carbonate in water, given that bicarbonate will also form?

Tags: solubility, environmental-chemistry

Calculate the solubility of lead (II) carbonate, $\ce{PbCO3}$, ($K_{\mathrm{sp}} = 1.5 \times 10^{-15}$) in water, given that carbonate is a stronger base than water, so will also form bicarbonate. When bicarbonate acts as an acid: \begin{align}
\ce{HCO3- &<--> H+ + CO3^2-} & K_{\mathrm{a}} &= 4.7 \times 10^{-11}.
\end{align}

I think the equation is, in light of airhuff's suggestion, $$\ce{PbCO3 -> Pb^2+ + CO3^2-}.$$
What I'm most confused about is how the bicarbonate and $K_\mathrm{a}$ comes into play in this question. It makes a traditional $K_\mathrm{sp}$ question a little trickier.

Possible answer?:
\begin{align}
\ce{PbCO3 &<--> Pb^2+ + CO3^2-} 
&\implies K_1 &= K_\mathrm{sp} = 1.5\times10^{-15}\\
\ce{CO3^2- + H2O &<--> HCO3- + OH-} &\implies K_2\\
\ce{PbCO3 + H2O &<--> Pb^2+ + HCO3- + OH-} &\implies K_3\\
\ce{HCO3- &<--> H+ + CO3^2-} &\implies K_4 &= K_\mathrm{a} = 4.7\times10^{-11}\\[3ex]
K_3 &= K_1 \cdot K_2\\
K_3 &= \frac{K_\mathrm{w}}{K_4}\\
K_2 &= \frac{1\times10^{-14}}{4.7\times10^{-11}}\\ &= 2.1\times10^{-9}\\
K_3 &= (1.5\times10^{-15})\cdot(2.1\times10^{-4})\\ &= 3.15\times10^{-19}\\
S_{\ce{PbCO3}} &= [\ce{Pb^2+}][\ce{HCO3-}]\\ &=[\ce{OH-}]\\
K_3 &= [\ce{Pb^2+}][\ce{HCO3-}][\ce{OH-}]\\ &= S^3\\
S &= \sqrt[3]{K_3} (3.15\times10^{-19})\\
  &= 6.8\times10^{-7}~\mathrm{M}\\
\end{align}

Does the way I solved it look okay?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will be closed shortly if you don't show some more work. How about writing out the chemical reaction for the solubility of $\ce{PbCO3}$? Take a shot at combining the reactions an calculating the solubility? I've seen you post some stuff before and I think you can at least make a good effort toward solving this one.

Comment: I've tried to solve this question and reached a final answer to what I think may be right?

Comment: @orthocresol , I think I got this pretty complex formatting right, other than that I couldn't figure out how to do a cubed root so did a power to the 1/3. You've been helpful in getting all this through my head and I just wanted to bounce this one off you...thx for any input. This message _will_ self destruct rather than be left here ;)

Comment: @airhuff any comments about the actual question will be most helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Greg, I just nominated this question to be reopened based on all the work you've put into it. This doesn't mean it _will_ be reopened, just that I think it should be. Regarding the formatting, it's _much_ easier to read when properly formatted. One of the reasons I did all that work to re-format was to increase the likelihood that it would be re-opened. I don't have the time to look closer at it now, but it looks like you're on the right track anyway.

Comment: @airhuff (square)roots: `\sqrt[3]{K_3}`. I reopened, +1 for effort!

Comment: I haven't worked out the answer, but yours isn't correct. You messed up a bit on the nomenclature for carbonic acid. $K_4 = K_{\alpha2}$ and $K_2 = K_{\beta2} = \dfrac{K_w}{K_{\alpha2}} $. The key to the solution is to note that $\ce{[Pb^{2+}] = [CO3^{2-}] + [HCO3^-] }$

Answer (score 3):

List known reactions and equilibrium constants

\begin{align}
\ce{PbCO3 &<--> Pb^2+ + CO3^2-} \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad K_\mathrm{sp} = 1.5\times10^{-15}\\
\ce{HCO3- &<--> H+ + CO3^2-} \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad K_\mathrm{a2} = 4.7\times10^{-11}\\
\ce{CO3^2- + H2O &<--> HCO3- + OH-} \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad K_\mathrm{b2} = \dfrac{K_\mathrm{w}}{K_\mathrm{a2}} = 2.13 \times 10^{-4}\\
\end{align}

Start off by just evaluating quick and dirty

- Assume $\ce{[Pb^{2+}] = [CO3^{2-}]}$, $\ce{[Pb^{2+}] = \sqrt{1.5\times10^{-15}} = 0.387 \times10^{-7}}$

OK, the assumption is no good and this is going to be fairly nasty...

- The pH is close to the autoionization of water
- $\ce{CO3^{2-}}$ is a strong base so $\ce{HCO3^{-}}$ can't be ignored.

**GIVEN:**

- Starting off with pure water so $\ce{[H+] = [OH-] } = 1\times 10^{-7}$ before $\ce{PbCO3}$ is dissolved.
- $\ce{[CO3^{2-}] = 0}$ and $\ce{[HCO3^-] = 0}$ before $\ce{PbCO3}$ is dissolved.

**WORK**

Know that

- The final pH > 7 due to the formation of $\ce{HCO3^{-}}$
- $\ce{[Pb^{2+}] = [CO3^{2-}] +[HCO3^-]}$
- $\ce{[OH^-]_{final} - [OH^-]_{water} = [HCO3^-] }$ or $\ce{[OH^-]_{final} = 1.00\times 10^{-7} + [HCO3^-] }$

For the ratio $ \dfrac{\ce{[CO3^{2-}]}}{\ce{[HCO3^-]}}$ we can use the expression of the $K_\mathrm{a2}$ equilibrium to find that:

- At pH 7 ratio = 0.00047
- At pH 8 ratio = 0.0047
- At pH 9 ratio = 0.047

So it would seem that $\ce{[HCO3^{2-}] >> [CO3^-]}$ is a reasonable assumption, which also means that $\ce{[Pb^{2+}] \approx [HCO3^-]}$.

Now we have the two equilibrium equations

$K_\mathrm{sp} = 1.5\times10^{-15} = \ce{[Pb^{2+}][CO3^{2-}]}$

$K_\mathrm{b2} = \dfrac{K_\mathrm{w}}{K_\mathrm{a2}} = \dfrac{\ce{[HCO3^-][OH-]}}{\ce{[CO3^{2-}]}}$

which we can multiply together to get

$\dfrac{K_\mathrm{w}K_\mathrm{sp}}{K_\mathrm{a2}} = \ce{[Pb^{2+}][HCO3^{-}][OH^-]}$

**APPROXIMATE CUBIC SOLUTION**

if we let $x = \ce{[Pb^{2+}]}$ then since $x = \ce{[Pb^{2+}] \approx [HCO3^-]}$ and $\ce{[OH-] = [HCO3^-] + 1.00\times10^{-7}}$ we have

$\dfrac{K_\mathrm{w}K_\mathrm{sp}}{K_\mathrm{a2}} =(x)(x)(x + 1\times10^{-7}) =x^3 + (1\times10^{-7})x^2$

Now if we multiply both sides by $10^{21}$ we are trying to solve:

$319.149 = x^3 + x^2$

neglecting the square term we get $x=\sqrt[3]{319.149} = 6.834$, or $\ce{[Pb^{2+}] = 6.834\times10^{-7}}$.

But looking at our cubic equation again

$319.149 = x^3 + x^2 \text{ =?= } 6.834^3 + 6.834^2 = 365.821 $

which is too far off since we need values to about 1%. Solving the cubic by iteration we get $x = 6.516$

> > Using 2 guesses then interpolation
> >     6.834           365.876
> >     6.000           252.000
> >     6.492           315.758
> >     6.517           319.257
> >     6.516           319.116
> >     Check
> >     $319.149 = x^3 + x^2 \text{ =?= } 6.516^3 + 6.516^2 = 319.116 $

which gives:

$\begin{align}
\ce{[Pb^{2+}]} &= 6.516 \times10^{-7}\\
\ce{[HCO3^{-}]} &= 6.516 \times10^{-7}\\
\ce{[OH^{-}]} &= 7.516 \times10^{-7}\\
\end{align}$

We can calculate

$\ce{[CO3^{2-}]} = \dfrac{K_\mathrm{sp}}{\ce{[Pb^{2+}]}} = 0.023\times10^{-7} $

$\ce{[H+]} = \dfrac{K_\mathrm{w}}{\ce{[OH-]}} = 0.133\times10^{-7}$

CHECK:

$\dfrac{\ce{[H+][CO3^{2-}]}}{\ce{[HCO3^{-}]}} = 4.695\times10^{-11}$

So to the correct number of significant figures we have

$\begin{align}
\ce{[Pb^{2+}]} &= 6.5 \times10^{-7}\\
\ce{[CO3^{2-}]} &= 0.023 \times10^{-7}\\
\ce{[HCO3^{-}]} &= 6.5 \times10^{-7}\\
\ce{[H^{+}]} &= 0.13 \times10^{-7}\text{,}\quad pH = 7.88\\
\ce{[OH^{-}]} &= 7.5 \times10^{-7}
\end{align}$

**EXACT FORMULIC SOLUTION**

Starting with the formula

$\dfrac{K_\mathrm{w}K_\mathrm{sp}}{K_\mathrm{a2}} = \ce{[Pb^{2+}][HCO3^{-}][OH^-]}$

We let $x = \ce{[Pb^{2+}]}$ as before.

$\ce{[HCO3^-] = [Pb^{2+}] - [CO3^{2-}] =} x - \dfrac{K_\mathrm{sp}}{x} = \dfrac{x^2 - K_\mathrm{sp}}{x}$

$\ce{[OH-] = [HCO3^-]} + \sqrt{K_\mathrm{w}} = \dfrac{x^2 - K_\mathrm{sp}}{x} + \sqrt{K_\mathrm{w}} = \dfrac{x^2 +(\sqrt{K_\mathrm{w}})x - K_\mathrm{sp}}{x}$

$\begin{align}
\dfrac{K_\mathrm{w}K_\mathrm{sp}}{K_\mathrm{a2}} &= (x)(\dfrac{x^2 - K_\mathrm{sp}}{x})(\dfrac{x^2 +(\sqrt{K_\mathrm{w}})x - K_\mathrm{sp}}{x})\\
\dfrac{K_\mathrm{w}K_\mathrm{sp}}{K_\mathrm{a2}}x &=(x^2 - K_\mathrm{sp})(x^2 +(\sqrt{K_\mathrm{w}})x - K_\mathrm{sp}) \\
\dfrac{K_\mathrm{w}K_\mathrm{sp}}{K_\mathrm{a2}}x &= x^4 + (\sqrt{K_\mathrm{w}})x^3 - 2K_\mathrm{sp}x^2 - K_\mathrm{sp}\sqrt{K_\mathrm{w}}x + K^2_\mathrm{sp}\\
0 &= x^4 + (\sqrt{K_\mathrm{w}})x^3 - 2K_\mathrm{sp}x^2 - \dfrac{K_\mathrm{w}K_\mathrm{sp}+ K_\mathrm{sp}K_\mathrm{a2}\sqrt{K_\mathrm{w}}}{K_\mathrm{a2}}x + K^2_\mathrm{sp}\\
\end{align}$

$x = 6.531198\times10^{-07}$, and other values same as Excel also...

**EXACT SOLUTION WITH EXCEL**

Solved first by using an excel spreadsheet (with too many significant figures, but extra digits help show that the calculations are consistent)...*

$\begin{align}
\ce{[Pb^{2+}]} &= 6.531199 \times10^{-7}\\
\ce{[CO3^{2-}]} &= 0.022967 \times10^{-7}\\
\ce{[HCO3^{-}]} &= 6.508231 \times10^{-7}\\
\ce{[H^{+}]} &= 0.133187 \times10^{-7}\text{,}\quad pH = 7.8755376\\
\ce{[OH^{-}]} &= 7.508230 \times10^{-7}
\end{align}$

CHECKS:

$\ce{[H^{+}][OH-] = 0.9999986\times 10^{-14}}$

$\ce{[Pb^{2+}][CO3^{2-}]} = 1.500020\times10^{-15} $

$\dfrac{\ce{[H+][CO3^{2-}]}}{\ce{[HCO3^{-}]}} = 4.700057\times10^{-11}$